# How to plot an interval in one axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to python and I'm trying to plot some couples (x,y) in one axis X  in the form of an interval. For example if I have the following couples (2,3),(2,4),(4,4),(1,3), I should produce the graph in the picture below.

I try this code but it doesn't give me the right result

```
def DrawGraph (RM):
    for i in range(0,RM.shape[0]-1):
        c1=lastOne2(RM,i)
        ax1=plt.subplot(1,1,1)
        if c1[0] == c1[1]:
            plt.plot(c1[0],c1[1],'ro')
        if c1[0] < c1[1]:
            ax1.barh(c1[0], c1[1], height=0.05)
        if c1[0] > c1[1]:
            ax1.barh(c1[1], c1[0], height=0.05)
    return plt
```

[image: desired output]

Comment: Have you tried writing some code yourself? If so, please post what you have so far.

Comment: I edit it  , thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am not sure why you are using `barh`. I think it is way simpler to just use a normal line and create some y values. Besides that, this should get you what you want. Note that you can specify any keyword arguments of `plt.plot` via `kwargs`. Also, `deltaY` lets so adjust how far the horizontal lines are apart.

```
# Import
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def DrawGraph(RM,deltaY=1,**kwargs):

    # Create figure
    ax=plt.subplot(1,1,1)

    for i in range(0,RM.shape[0]):

        # Grab current interval
        c1=RM[i]

        # Create y-values and shift intervals up by (i+1)*deltaY
        y=(i+1)*deltaY*np.ones((2,1))

        # Draw
        if c1[0] == c1[1]:
            ax.plot([c1[0]],[i*deltaY],'o',**kwargs)
        if c1[0] < c1[1]:
            ax.plot(c1,y,**kwargs)
        if c1[0] > c1[1]:
            ax.plot(c1,y,lw=lw,**kwargs)

    # Set ylim so it looks nice
    ax.set_ylim([0,deltaY*(i+2)])   

    return ax

# Define intervals
intervals=np.array([(2,3),(2,4),(4,4),(1,3)])


# Plot
DrawGraph(intervals,lw=5,c='b')

# Draw
plt.show()
```

This will get you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop should suffice.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
p = [(2,3),(2,4),(4,4),(1,3)]

def drawp(p, dy=1,**kw):
    for i,x in enumerate(p):
        plt.plot(np.unique(x),[i*dy]*len(np.unique(x)),
                 marker="s"*(2-len(np.unique(x))), ms=kw.get("lw",2),**kw)

drawp(p, color="crimson")

plt.show()
```

[image]